# What is "/mgmt/usr/bin/loginshell" in Cisco ACI?

Tags: cisco

I notice that Cisco ACI is actually running on some kind of Linux system?

```
ABC-ACI-APC-01# echo $SHELL
/mgmt/usr/bin/loginshell
ABC-ACI-APC-01#
```

What kind of shell is this?

```
/mgmt/usr/bin/loginshell
```

There is no such file or directory in the system.

```
ABC-ACI-APC-01# ls -lha /mgmt/usr/bin/loginshell
ls: cannot access /mgmt/usr/bin/loginshell: No such file or directory
ABC-ACI-APC-01#
```

In fact, there is no such `/mgmt/usr/` directory at all.

```
ABC-ACI-APC-01# ls -lha /mgmt
total 12K
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4.0K Jun  9  2018 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root 4.0K Jun  9  2018 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Jun  9  2018 bin
ABC-ACI-APC-01#
```

Comment: It's customized shell.

Comment: Thanks @RonTrunk, I was trying to check that file, but it's not there. Even the `/mgmt/usr/` directory not there.

Comment: It's highly restricted shell that doesn't allow you to poke around under the hood, to prevent exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: It is one of many varieties commonly referred to as “jail shells” that provide a shell with limited access to the underlying system.

Comment: ACI is a very complicated pile of *stuff*. The CLI is started from an admin context to which the shell has no access. It's more than a simple `chroot` but not a complete container. (trust me, you do *not* want to understand this house of cards.)